# Proxy - Convert HTTP requests to SOCKS5

Tags: http, proxy, socks, tor

I'm currently doing some testing work with TOR and ran in to a small problem. Tor's client only supports receiving connections through a SOCKS5 protocol, but the applications I'm using only support HTTP Proxy Protocals.

Is it possible to put something in the middle? So that for example it went.

My Program (HTTP Only) > HTTP to SOCKS Converter > Tor SOCKS5 Server

Googled around quite a bit, I found information for SOCKS to HTTP, but not the other way around. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was asked and answered on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/423563/convert-http-requests-to-socks5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put any HTTP proxy that supports SOCKS in the middle. Once the proxy [Polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/) was commonly used for this purpose and it should still work and before that Privoxy was used.